# Retrieving the selected element in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, cookies

I have a list, its elements are come from the DB,

I want to see the selected elements all the time, especially after refresing the page.

It's like;

```
<select id="select-firm" class="form-control" name="firmId" size="20">
</select>
```

I am using Ajax call to retrieve elements.

What should I do to see the selected element all the time ?

Thank you

Comment: You want to call the jQuery `.val` function `$("#select-firm").val()` or something else? I do not understand you clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, depends on if you want to save the selection just for the specific user locally or to store the selection on the server.

you can use

> local storage

or a

> cookie

to save the selected option locally , and check if something was saved on the next refresh.

Or return the selection to the server to save it, and when you will refresh the page next time the server should give you the list of options and the already selected option.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide mapping and print the selected entry on the server.

```
<?php

$selected = 3;

$output = [];

foreach( $lists as $item ){

$output[] = '<option value="' . $item['id'] . '"' . ($item['id']==$selected?' selected="selected"':null) . '>' . $item['name'] . '</option>';

}

echo $output;
```